# Why isn't nginx saving changes to the conf file in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, server, timeout, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting 504 errors in my elastic beanstalk web app after 60s so I have implemented timeout extension changes to the config file in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, as well as setting types_hash_max_size to 1024 as per the error logs. Are there any other error logs I should be checking in my AWS instance or am I implementing the changes incorrectly?

Here is the nginx config with the changes I have added:

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    200000;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 90;
        client_body_timeout   90;
        keepalive_timeout     90;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout    90;
        proxy_read_timeout    90;
        send_timeout          90;
        types_hash_max_size   1024;
        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

and here is the error as it appears in the logs

```
[warn] 13416#13416: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, I will try to change

```
server {
  # More config...

  types_hash_max_size 4096; # Defaut value is 1024
  variables_hash_max_size 8192;

  # More config...
}
```

Try it out and late me know about you still got the error.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Try to increse types_hash_bucket_size to 4096 and remove the hash_bucket size line again, i will update my awsner

Comment: the awsner are updated, can you paste the error again, you say "same error" but can you paste it, need to see the current error if its still happen after small changes

Comment: So i rebuilt the AWS instance with this added to the nginx config file 
```
  types_hash_max_size 4096; # Defaut value is 1024
  variables_hash_max_size 8192;
```
however when viewing the config file in AWS, these changes don't appear, but 
```
types_hash_max_size 1024;
```
does appear, and the error logs still output the same error message:
```
[warn] 13416#13416: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
```

Comment: its look like its not loading the right nginx config, can you pls check what config there are loaded into your nginx? normal its from /etc/nginx/ or something like that (little time since i have usen nginx) but when the config not accept the new settings it look like its load the wrong config into nginx on reboot